# How to prevent writing duplicate loops?

Tags: wp-query, loop

So i have some pages where i want to show my custom post type 'events' only by the last 5 posts (secondary query: WP_Query object) and some pages where i want to show all posts (for instance archive template as is_main_query). I hate duplicate code - but i cant seem to outthink a way to not write loop code, even though it should display same structure, in separate places.
For instance; in my loop.php file I loop through all main query posts with have_posts(). But in my secondary queries where I use WP_Query, I cant call that loop file because its not a main query. Then I'll have to look up that specific query with $secondary_query->have_posts(), so i end up writing loop code where i call WP_Query..

So to wrap it up :-) is there a way I dont know about to use my loop file on secondary queries??
This is kind of what I want to do:

```
$event_query = new WP_query($args);
get_template_part('loop', 'home'); //calling loop.php
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the control structure outside the template file and just put the repeatable markup and template tags inside.

```
$event_query = new WP_query($args);
if( $event_query->have_posts() ){
    while( $event_query->have_posts() ){
        $event_query->the_post();
        get_template_part('loop', 'home');
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks Milo, was about to add that as it seems from the comment to my answer that there are a slight misunderstanding on the part of the OP

Comment: Of course! That is what im looking for! Brilliant - thanks and have a nice weekend all of you!

Comment: this should be marked as the answer.. ;)

Comment: Good idea - done :-)